# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "me" at path "_id" for model "wallet"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, redux, populate

> > How are you all, I want to get a user's data in a node. Means all the data of a single user. Like this is one register data and the
> >     other is of payment. Now in this I want to get all the payments of how
> >     much a user has paid. I have tried this. But this error is coming
> >     Maybe I am not able to write the code correctly. So please guide me.

get method of user payments

```
router.get('/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    UserWallet.find()
        .select("user", " id user")
        .populate("user ", "_id user")
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.json({ result })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error.message)
            res.status(500).send('Server Error')
        })
});
```

> Post method of user payments

```
router.post(
    '/payment/add',
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const user = await users.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
            const { bankName, tranferRefCode, amount } = req.body;
            const newPayment = new UserWallet({
                bankName,
                tranferRefCode,
                amount,
                username: user.username,
                avatar: user.avatar,
                user: req.user.id
            });
            await newPayment.save().then(payment => {
                res.json({ newPayment: payment })
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Server Error');
        }
    }
);
```

> Schema of user payment

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const walletSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    bankName: {
        type: String,
    },
    tranferRefCode: {
        type: String,
    },
    amount: {
        type: String,
    },
    username: {
        type: String
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = Wallet = mongoose.model('wallet', walletSchema)
```

> Result of payment add

```
{
    "newPayment": {
        "_id": "5ec0a61597d09440249a1dcc",
        "bankName": "sbi",
        "tranferRefCode": "kfjalskdfjkasdfjajs",
        "amount": "1000",
        "username": "s",
        "avatar": "https://gravatar.comxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
        "paymentBy": "5eb2fa29d37d9a08741621c8",
        "date": "2020-05-17T02:48:53.662Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You might have invalid data in your database. If you don't define `_id` in your schema, mongoose will automatically set it as `ObjectId`. You probably have an invalid record with `_id: 'me'`, try to update the record with a valid `ObjectId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is 100% worked

```
 router.get('/myPayment/user', auth, async (req, res) => {
        UserWallet.find({ paymentBy: req.user.id })
            .populate("paymentBy", "_id username email")
            .then(myPanment => {
                res.json({myPanment})
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({msg: err})            
            })
    });
```

> This Response Result

```
{
    "myPanment": [
        {
            "_id": "5ec38e65b4af0b1e4ce9ff95",
            "bankName": "PUNB",
            "tranferRefCode": "xsxsdsdsdmskdmskdmksdmS",
            "amount": "51000",
            "username": "satendrasingh",
            "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/xxxxxxxx?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
            "paymentBy": {
                "_id": "5eb1562e166a03269c3f2d82",
                "username": "xxxxx",
                "email": "s@gmail.com"
            },
            "date": "2020-05-19T07:44:37.870Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ec38f34dd1b131ac4a3d644",
            "bankName": "Singh",
            "tranferRefCode": "Singh7536051428",
            "amount": "8000",
            "username": "satendrasingh",
            "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/xxxxxxxxx?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
            "paymentBy": {
                "_id": "5eb1562e166a03269c3f2d82",
                "username": "xxx",
                "email": "s@gmail.com"
            },
            "date": "2020-05-19T07:48:04.286Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ec38f62d12b642de859083a",
            "bankName": "ljhjkhkjh",
            "tranferRefCode": "jhksjhjkhjk5h3k5jhj53h4j53hk5hj5k345657567",
            "amount": "548732",
            "username": "satendrasingh",
            "avatar": "https://gravatar.com/avatar/xxxxxxxxxx?d=mm&r=pg&s=200",
            "paymentBy": {
                "_id": "5eb1562e166a03269c3f2d82",
                "username": "xxxxxxxx",
                "email": "s@gmail.com"
            },
            "date": "2020-05-19T07:48:50.885Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```